# Looping : 10,000 arrays (time wasting) vs 1 global array (memory wasting)

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

For performance reason, I have a game map divided in 10,000 tiles. Each tile has an array of entities. Thus, entities entering/leaving a tile is pushed/removed into/from the corresponding array.

On the other hand, to avoid to loop on the 10,000 arrays to **update** **all** the entities every *x ms*, what is the most efficient way to handle arrays ?

Besides the tiles array, should I create one global array containing all the entities from all the tiles ? Is it not memory wasting ?

Comment: I just couldn't get your model well. Can you not establish an observer pattern so that your entities publish their state changes at each move and your tiles to subscribe for them. [Observer and PubSub pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript) is what you are looking for. Checking all 10K tiles every x msec is a terrible idea.

Comment: I think you should use a matrix zoning patern. By say, block of 500 tiles accoding to zoning. So you have 200 array elements of 500 tiles. Doing so the zone reference is passed and you loop across the sub array.

Comment: Yes, a global array with all entities to loop over will be more efficient than looping over all tiles if you have many tiles without any entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common dichotomy in performance tuning, processing vs memory.
My answer as always, (especially regarding performance) is "it depends".  The only real way to know is to measure both and see if the speed/memory usage fits within some acceptable bounds. eg. If you want 60fps you have to be <16ms per frame, no questions asked.

My suggestion would be to implement it in whichever way is the most logical to the reader (ie. you/your team) and only once it works mangle the code for performance gains (and then, only once you can measure them). This prevents you "optimizing" code and making it unreadable/unmaintainable (or, at least less so) without having evidence it is required and that it is an actual improvement.